# Unable to access User object in models.py of Post app: Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-sessions

I'm trying to access user object in models.py
I have two apps (users & employees) under my Django project, I just want to know which user added employee in the employees model at the time of displaying the employees details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will helps you.

https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/current_user.html

If you are using default admin panel

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I just added a ForeignKey to my model & added a save_model() method to admin.py to set added_by to current user